# From C# after getting IBM MQ message how to identify message data type? Is it Object or String type?

Tags: string, object, get, ibm-mq

In our company we are using IBM MQ server for message queueing. For the same queue we are putting both String and Object type data message with the help of methods WriteObject and WriteString.

The challenge is occured when it comes to consumption(read message) of queue. Since the Get data can be both Object or String we need to decide which method to use ReadString or ReadObject on the MQMessage instance. I made workaround like firstly using ReadObject method, if an exception occured then try it with ReadString.

**I did not like this workaround, is there any way to identify message data type after calling MQQueue instance's Get method?**

Here below you can find my workaround:

```
    public object GetMessage(string queueName) {

        MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager("queueManagerName", "channel", "connection");
        MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
        queueGetMessageOptions.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;

        try {
            queueRead = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
            queueMessage = new MQMessage();
            queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
            queueRead.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);

            try {
                var readObject = queueMessage.ReadObject();
                return readObject;
            } catch (SerializationException) { } // if message in queue not a object

            queueMessage.DataOffset = 0;
            var stringMsg = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
            return stringMsg;

        } catch (MQException exp) {                
            if (exp.ReasonCode != 2033) {
                log.ErrorFormat("MQException: ResonCode: {0}, {1}", exp.ReasonCode, exp.Message);                    
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a horrible design.

First off, why are you putting 2 different message types into the same queue?  Bad, very bad idea.  You should be using 2 different queues.  What, does someone think queues are scarce or rare?  You should be handing out queues like candy.

Secondly, if you really need to go with this design then you should read the MQ Knowledge Center on [MQMD structure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097390_.htm?lang=en).  It contains a field called 'Message Type'.  Most applications use 'Message Type' to contain either 'MQMT_DATAGRAM' or 'MQMT_REQUEST' but you can set your own values starting with 'MQMT_APPL_FIRST'.

So, define a couple of constants:

```
public const int MY_MSG_OBJECT = MQC.MQMT_APPL_FIRST + 1;
public const int MY_MSG_STRING = MQC.MQMT_APPL_FIRST + 2;
```

Hence, the sending application putting a string message would do:

```
MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
sendmsg.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
sendmsg.MessageType = MY_MSG_STRING;
sendmsg.WriteString("This is a test message");
queue.Put(sendmsg, pmo);
```

and the sending application putting an object message would do:

```
MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
sendmsg.Format = MQC.MQFMT_NONE;
sendmsg.MessageType = MY_MSG_OBJECT;
sendmsg.WriteObject(someObject);
queue.Put(sendmsg, pmo);
```

The receiving application would do:

```
MQMessage rcvmsg = new MQMessage();
queue.Get(rcvmsg, gmo);
// Check the Message Type
if (rcvmsg.MessageType == MY_MSG_STRING)
{
   readString = queue.ReadString();
}
else if (rcvmsg.MessageType == MY_MSG_OBJECT)
{
   readObject = queue.ReadObject();
}
else
{
   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Error: Unknown message type.");
}
```

Comment: Hello Roger,

Thanks for your response. I agree with you that it is bad design, but it is because we get message from external system.

I also asked my question in IBM's forum, there also got an answer. Both your's and answer from IBM forum can be used as a workaround.

Here I am also sharing the response of IBM Forum : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0302a4c6-3ba2-4bd0-a5b3-77538d4c1674

Comment: Matching MQMessage.MessageType against your constant didn't work for me. I ended up comparing MQMessage.Format (which returns `"MQSTR     "`) to decide which Read method to use. Was there a change in a API (using MQ9)?

Comment: My use case is that I'm trying to log all the messages that come across all topics, so I set up a wildcard topic/queue and am now trying to write a windows service.